# Third Level Category URL's issues

Tags: category, url

I'm building a tree view for my magento site. Its all working fine. But the only problem is that When I go into 4th level categories the URL path of the category is not coming properly.

for example.

Lets say I have the following url path

```
testsite.com/index.php/accessories/interior-accessories/electronic/
```

this is my 3rd level category url. The problem is that I would have another sub category under  electronic like,

```
testsite.com/index.php/accessories/interior-accessories/electronic/sub-cat
```

, but magento does not give me this path. it will only give upto the 3rd level category.

This is the code that I am using.

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
echo Mage::getUrl($cat->getUrlPath());
```

any ideas?

Comment: Try with `echo $cat->getUrl();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments...
You can get the url of a category like this:

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
$url = $cat->getUrl();
```